# parseInt(code) Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add some code to my jquery weather to translate the condition weather text to another lang . I want call parseInt(code) to translate the weather condition text but have error

code :

```
    function conditionCode(code) {

  var code = parseInt(code);
  var text = '';

  if (code == 0) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("tornado"); }
  if (code == 1) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§ØµÙØ© Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø³ØªÙˆØ§Ø¦ÙŠØ©"); }
  if (code == 2) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø¥Ø¹ØµØ§Ø± "); }
  if (code == 3) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø¹ÙˆØ§ØµÙ Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø¹Ø¯ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø¯ÙŠØ¯Ø©"); }
  if (code == 4) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø¹ÙˆØ§ØµÙ Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø¹Ø¯ÙŠØ©"); }
  if (code == 5) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¶ ' + em("Ø§Ù…Ø·Ø§Ø±") + ' Ùˆ ' + em("Ø«Ù„Ø¬") + ' Ù†Ø²ÙˆÙ„'; }
  if (code == 6) { var text = 'Ù…Ù…Ø¹ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¶ ' + em("Ø§Ù…Ø·Ø§Ø±") + ' Ùˆ ' + em("Ù…Ø·Ø± Ù…ØªØ¬Ù…Ø¯") + ' Ù†Ø²ÙˆÙ„'; }
  if (code == 7) { var text = 'with a mix of ' + em("snow") + ' and ' + em("sleet") + ' in the area'; }
  if (code == 8) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¶ ' + em("Ø±Ø°Ø§Ø° ÙƒØ«ÙŠÙ"); }
  if (code == 9) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø±Ø°Ø§Ø°") + ' Ù†Ø²ÙˆÙ„'; }
  if (code == 10) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø­Ø¨Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±Ø¯") + ' Ù†Ø²ÙˆÙ„'; }
  if (code == 11 || code == 12) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø§Ù…Ø·Ø§Ø± Ø®ÙÙŠÙØ©"); }
  if (code == 13) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¶' + em("Ù‡Ø¨Ø§Øª") + ' Ù†Ø²ÙˆÙ„'; }
  if (code == 14) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¶ ' + em("Ø«Ù„ÙˆØ¬ Ø®ÙÙŠÙØ©"); }
  if (code == 15) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¶ Ø§Ù„Ù‡Ø¨ÙˆØ¨  ' + em("Ù‡Ø¨ÙˆØ¨ Ø«Ù„ÙˆØ¬"); }
  if (code == 16) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¶ ' + em("Ø«Ù„Ø¬") + ' Ù†Ø²ÙˆÙ„'; }
  if (code == 17) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("hail") + ' Ù†Ø²ÙˆÙ„'; }
  if (code == 18) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("sleet") + ' Ù†Ø²ÙˆÙ„'; }
  if (code == 19) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ù…ØºØ¨Ø±Ø©") + ' Ø§ÙˆØ¶Ø§Ø¹'; }
  if (code == 20) { var text = 'Ùˆ ' + em("Ø¶Ø¨Ø§Ø¨"); }
  if (code == 21) { var text = 'Ùˆ ' + em("Ø¶Ø¨Ø§Ø¨ÙŠ"); }
  if (code == 22) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø¯Ø®Ø§Ù† ÙÙŠ Ø³Ù…Ø§Ø¡"); }
  if (code == 23) { var text = 'Ùˆ ' + em("Ù…ØªÙ‡ÙŠØ¬"); }
  if (code == 26) { var text = 'Ùˆ ' + em("ØºØ§Ø¦Ù…"); }
  if (code == 27 || code == 28) { var text = 'Ùˆ ' + em("ØºØ§Ù„Ø¨Ø§Ù‹ ØºØ§Ø¦Ù…"); }
  if (code == 29 || code == 30 || code == 44) { var text = 'Ùˆ ' + em("ØºØ§Ø¦Ù… Ø¬Ø²Ø¦ÙŠØ§"); }
  if (code == 31) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø³Ù…Ø§Ø¡ ØµØ§ÙÙŠØ©"); }
  if (code == 32) { var text = 'Ùˆ ' + em("Ù…Ø´Ù…Ø³"); }
  if (code == 33 || code == 34) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø·Ù‚Ø³ Ù…Ø¹ØªØ¯Ù„"); }
  if (code == 35) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ Ù…Ø²ÙŠØ¬ Ù…Ù† ' + em("Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù…Ø·Ø§Ø±") + ' Ùˆ ' + em("ÙˆØ§Ø¨Ù„"); }
  if (code == 37) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¶ ' + em("Ø¹ÙˆØ§ØµÙ Ø±Ø¹Ø¯ÙŠØ© Ø´Ø¯ÙŠØ¯s"); }
  if (code == 38 || code == 39) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø¹ÙˆØ§ØµÙ Ø±Ø¹Ø¯ÙŠØ© Ù…ØªÙØ±Ù‚Ø©"); }
  if (code == 40) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¶ ' + em("Ø²Ø®Ø§Øª Ù…ØªÙØ±Ù‚Ø©"); }
  if (code == 41 || code == 43) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø§Ù„Ø«Ù„ÙˆØ¬ Ø§Ù„ÙƒØ«ÙŠÙØ©") + ' Ù‡Ø¨ÙˆØ·'; }
  if (code == 42) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø«Ù„ÙˆØ¬ ÙƒØ«ÙŠÙ") + ' Ù‡Ø¨ÙˆØ·'; }
  if (code == 45) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø§Ù…Ø·Ø§Ø±") + ' Ùˆ ' + em("Ø¨Ø±ÙˆÙ‚"); }
  if (code == 46) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ ' + em("Ø«Ù„ÙˆØ¬ Ø®ÙÙŠÙ") + ' Ù†Ø²ÙˆÙ„'; }
  if (code == 47) { var text = 'Ù…Ø¹ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¶ ' + em("Ø¹ÙˆØ§ØµÙ Ø±Ø¹Ø¯ÙŠØ© Ø´Ø¯ÙŠØ¯Ø©"); }
  if (text == '') {
    var text = '  </h1>';
  } else {
    // Add spaces before and after text
    var text = ' ' + text + ' ';
  }

  return text;
}
```

and have error here

```
html += '<div class="weatherDesc">'+ feed.item.condition.text +' ' + text + '</div>';
```

have error ncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined

Comment: Just wondering what is wrong with switch statement? !

Comment: OP should probably do an array like `var textArray = ["text1","text2"]...` and just assign code to this. `var text = textArray[code];`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `text` outside of the scope of `conditionCode`, so it doesn't exist and the compiler complains.

`var` declares a variable in the scope of the current function.

---

Asides:

- Don't redeclare a variable within a function. Do it once, at the top, not every time you assign a value to a variable.
- Don't use `parseInt` without a radix argument (`parseInt(foo, 10)` for decimal values) or you can get unexpected results.

Comment: mean change to the var ?

Comment: You should remove each var in all of your if statement inside the conditioncode function